Large iCloud Network Traffic Normal?
While using my mobile data plan for tethering with my Mac i noticed that it quickly reached the maximum data limit of 40GB per month. To investigate where this traffic was coming from I installed a network monitor software.
When waking my Mac today from sleep I quickly opened the software and realized that in a matter of around 5 minutes the Mac used the cloudd process to connect to icloud-content.com in order to download a total of 5,3 GB of data.
I know that this is an official Apple domain and like the name suggests probably does a lot of desired iCloud synchronization. But 5,3 GB still seems a little excessive to me. It uploaded not even a single MB (845kB) in the same amount of time. And iCloud Photo sync wasn't even turned on due to low power mode turned on (manual trigger needed in the Photos app).
Is this normal behavior that others observe as well? What exactly is my Mac downloading from the Apple servers if it's not photos? My iCloud drive is pretty empty (less than 100MB) and I didn't change any files lately.
